# How to show that $\chi_R(x) \nabla \frac 1{|x|} \in L^1(\mathbb R^3) \cap L^{3/2}(\mathbb R^3)$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces

Let $\chi_R(x)$ be a smooth function such that $\chi_R(x)=1$ if $|x| \le R$, $\chi_R(x) = 0$ if $|x| \ge 2R$, and $0 \le \chi_R(x) \le 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^3$.

How can we show that
 $\chi_R(x) \nabla \frac 1{|x|} \in L^1(\mathbb R^3) \cap L^{3/2}(\mathbb R^3)$?

In particular, I'm stuck at the $\chi_R(x) \nabla \frac 1{|x|} \in L^{3/2}(\mathbb R^3)$ part, I got
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \left|\chi_R(x) \nabla \frac 1{|x|}\right|^{3/2} dx \le \int_{B(0,2R)} \left|\nabla \frac 1{|x|}\right|^{3/2} dx = \int_{B(0,2R)}\frac 1{|x|^3} dx =\infty$$

so I got $\infty$ but obviously I'm trying to get less than $\infty$. I think my inequality might be too crude.

**Edit:** This is more precise and seems to me more plausible, but I'm still not sure if this answers my question:
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \left|\chi_R(x) \nabla \frac 1{|x|}\right|^{3/2} dx \color{red}{<} \int_{B(0,2R)} \left|\nabla \frac 1{|x|}\right|^{3/2} dx = \int_{B(0,2R)}\frac 1{|x|^3} dx =\infty$$
(I figured it was a strict inequality because $\chi_R(x) < 1$ as $|x|$ is close enough to $2R$. Wishful thinking, though: the first integral is still equal to $\infty$.)

Comment: I don't see any problems with your reasoning. If $r=|x|$, then $\nabla (1/r)$ behaves like $r^{-2}$, therefore the integrand behaves like $r^{-3}$, which is not integrable in $3$-dimensioned space. The estimations are not crude, since the problem at $|x|\to+\infty $ is compensated by $\chi$, but the singularity in $|x|=0$ is unaffected by $\chi$. Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: And you can always write the estimations in another direction: $$\left\|\chi_R(x) \nabla(1/|x|)\right\|^{3/2}_{L^{3/2}(\Bbb R^3)}\ge\int_{B(0,R)}|\chi_R (x)\nabla(1/|x|)|^{3/2}\,dx,$$ etc

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I got this problem from page 423 of this paper "Propagation of Moments and Regularity for the 3-dimensional Vlasov-Poisson system": http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/pdfcache/PPN356556735_0105/PPN356556735_0105___LOG_0023.pdf

Comment: Hm, I'll take a look into it, but I can't find a solution at the moment.

Comment: @Newdayrising: Your edit doesn't solve the problem: if $f < g$, it is *not* always true that $\int f < \int g$: take $f=x$ and $g = x^2$ on $[1, \infty)$ - both integrals are infinite, therefore equal. This fact precisely cancels your reasoning.

Comment: @Newdayrising: Another oddity is that they claim that $\chi _R \nabla \frac 1 {|x|}$ is bounded in $L^1 \cap L^{\frac 3 2}$. Bounded in what sense? As a vector-valued function clearly not, since this is not bounded around $0$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: Now, I'm really curious: does my answer contain any mistake? If so, please signal it to me. If not, why doesn't the OP accept the answer, and why haven't you awarded the bounty?

Comment: @AlexM. there is nothing wrong with your answer, this delay only means that some people don't have access to Internet on summer weekends (plus 15th of August is also a holiday in France...) =)

Comment: @AlexM. I appreciate your response and I'm convinced thoroughly that the argument in your answer is 100% correct. I'm just not "accepting" the answer because I'm still as confused as you are with the paper claiming that $\chi_R \nabla \frac 1{|x|}$ is bounded in a certain sense.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is ***not*** in $L^{\frac 3 2} (\Bbb R^3)$!

Split $\Bbb R^3$ into three regions: $\Bbb R^3 = B(0,R) \cup \overline {B(0, 2R) \setminus B(0,R)} \cup (\Bbb R^3 \setminus B(0, 2R))$. The first two intersect only along $|x| = R$, which is a negligible set, therefore you may decompose your integral into a sum of three integrals corresponding to the above union.

The middle set is closed and bounded, therefore compact. Since $\left| \chi _R \nabla \frac 1 {|x|} \right| ^{\frac 3 2}$ is continuous on it, it will also be integrable.

On the third set, $\chi _R$ is identically $0$, so this is trivial.

Let us focus, then, on $\int \limits _{B(0,R)} \left| \chi _R \nabla \frac 1 {|x|} \right| ^{\frac 3 2} \ \Bbb d x$. Introducing the shorthand $B = B(0,R)$ this is, in fact, just

$$\int \limits _B \left| \nabla \frac 1 {|x|} \right| ^{\frac 3 2} \ \Bbb d x = \int \limits _B \left| - \frac {(x_1, x_2, x_3)} {|x|^3} \right| ^{\frac 3 2} \ \Bbb d x = \int \limits _B \frac {|x| ^{\frac 3 2}} {|x| ^{\frac 9 2}} \ \Bbb d x = \int \limits _B \frac 1 {|x| ^3} \ \Bbb d x .$$

Switching to polar coordinates

$$\begin{align}
x_1 &= r \cos \beta \cos \alpha \\
x_2 &= r \cos \beta \sin \alpha \\
x_3 &= r \sin \beta \\
r &\in (0,R), \quad \alpha \in (0, 2\pi), \quad \beta \in \left( - \frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2 \right) ,
\end{align} $$

the integral becomes

$$\int \limits _0 ^{2 \pi} \int \limits _{-\frac \pi 2} ^{\frac \pi 2} \int \limits _0 ^R \frac 1 {r^3} r^2 \cos \beta \ \Bbb d r \ \Bbb d \beta \ \Bbb d \alpha = 4 \pi \int \limits _0 ^R \frac 1 r \ \Bbb d r = \infty ,$$

therefore the integral on the first set is infinite, hence $\chi _R \nabla \frac 1 {|x|} \notin L^{\frac 3 2} (\Bbb R^3)$.

---

In fact, to see what are the $p \ge 1$ with $\chi _R \nabla \frac 1 {|x|} \in L^p (\Bbb R^3)$, redo all of the above changing $\frac 3 2$ into $p$: the integral on the first set will become

$$\int \limits _B \frac 1 {|x| ^{2p}} \ \Bbb d x = 4 \pi \int \limits _0 ^R \frac 1 {r ^{2p-2}} \ \Bbb d r ,$$

and this is finite whenever $2p-2 < 1$, i.e. $p < \frac 3 2$ (funnily, your problem concerns precisely the limit case $p = \frac 3 2$).